# socket programming with linux and windows in c language

Tags: sockets

is it possible to implement socket programming between two different OS?

Suppose I am using linux-Ubuntu in one system and in other system windows OS,
now is it possible to implement socket programming between these two OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use sockets to talk between different OSes. The APIs may or may not be identical, but everything should work.

The main thing you have to take care of is the byte order when sending data on the wire. This [link](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/ipstructsdata.html#byteorder) explains byteorder and how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the possibility of socket connections from different os is not the question here :-)

If you want to use the same source of your implementation on windows and linux you can use boost socket in connection with boost asio. Both parts of the boost lib work on windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

2 operating systems Network Programming API may be different, but you can communicate with each other.

**Simple example is accessing http://google.com from your Windows/Linux/Mac-OSX machine.**

**Google's Web Server may be running in Linux and implemented using python socket programming, but you are seeing the page/content in a Web Browser which is implemented using C/C++ running under Windows/Linux/Mac-OSX**